# App crashes after .putExtra intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm trying to send a variable from one activity to another. When I try to test the app on my phone, it crashes and says the app has stopped working.

Code from sending side

```
if (id==R.id.action_cart){

        Intent good1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Scroll.class);

        good1.putExtra("intVariableName", 5);
        startActivity(good1);

        TextView hides = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        hides.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

and code on receiving side

```
public class Scroll extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);

    btn.setText(intValue);



}}
```

If you know what the issue is please let me know. I've spent hours looking for a solution. Thank you

Comment: log cat is always helpfull

Comment: @DroidGalaxy Please paste the error log of the crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to move this `TextView btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);` inside `oncreate` because before `oncreate` there is no layout attached to `Scroll` activity and finding `textview` by using this `findViewById(R.id.text)` will result in a failure hence crash

```
public class Scroll extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll);
        btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text)
        //^^^^
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
        btn.setText(""+intValue);                
      }
}
```

Note : Use appropriate naming convention for clarity , like `textViewVar` for `TextView` instead of `btn` and convert your `int` value to `text` using `""+value` because `TextView` allow only `String` to use

Comment: Still the app may crash at `btn.setText(intValue)` since there may be no resource for intValue. Change to `btn.setText(String.valueOf(intValue)`.

Comment: @PavanPatil actually there will be either always `0` (default value ) or the passed value although they should be in form of string

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this call: `btn.setText(intValue);`: string resource ID with value 5 does not exist. Try replacing it with `btn.setText(Integer.toString(intValue));`

Answer (score -1):

In your activity

```
public class Scroll extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView btn ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll);
    btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text); // initialize your button here
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);

    btn.setText(String.valueOf(intValue));



}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
    if (id==R.id.action_cart){
         //hide views before moving
           TextView hides = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            hides.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Intent good1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Scroll.class);
            good1.putExtra("intVariableName", 5);
            startActivity(good1);

        }
```

and in Recieving activity
   put this in oncreate

```
btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
```

Like this

```
 public class Scroll extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView btn ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll);
        btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
        btn.setText(intValue);



    }}
```

Answer (score -1):

change a line to: **btn.setText(String.valueOf(intValue));**

```
public class Scroll extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll);

    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);

    btn.setText(String.valueOf(intValue));
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Replace your code by this**

```
public class Scroll extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scroll);

        TextView btn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

        Intent mIntent = getIntent();
        int intValue = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);

        btn.setText(intValue);

    }
}
```

Comment: That is not the proper answer